# how to close a blocking socket while it is waiting to receive data?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a service that uses a blocking socket to receive data. The problem I have is that I do not know how to properly close the socket if it is still waiting for data. Below is a short snip of how I am opening and waiting for data: I do not want to implement timeouts as according to the python documentation the socket must be blocking in order to use `makefile`.

I may be going about this completely wrong as I am new to programming with sockets.

EDIT:

It should be noted that the I cannot alter how the server operates.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
reader = s.makefile("rb")
line = reader.readline()
```

Comment: Typical practice in C is to send a signal to the thread waiting for the socket.  The signal handler can `longjmp` out or simply cause the `read` to fail with `EINTR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to close this socket is to ask the server to close it.

If server close the client socket, the client will receive a "Connection reset by peer" error, and it may break the blocking receive.

Another solution would be to not use `readline()` and put a timeout on your socket (indefinite wait could wait.... indefinitely)

Comment: I don't have access to the server... But after scratching my head for some time I thought of the possibility of coding a proxy server... Might be over complicating this though..

Comment: You may be right. I am spending to much time with trying to make readline() work instead of just looking for newlines myself...

Comment: The client will receive a null from readLine() actually, not an exception. And there's no reason why readLine() can't be combined with a socket timeout.

Comment: @EJP : according to the python doc about [socket.makefile()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=makefile#socket.socket.makefile) you cannot use it with socket that have a timeout

Comment: Hmm. The python doc also says that fgets(3) throws away NUL bytes, which makes me wonder how accurate the Python documentation is, and what happens if a socket with a timeout is passed to socket.makefile()?

Comment: As davidbonnet said, calling `socket.shutdown()` before closing it terminates blocking `readline()`

Answer (score 6):

There is a quite simple solution. Given a socket and a reader file object like `rfile = socket.makefile('rb')`, in order to make `rfile.readline()` return immediately when the socket is closed, you need to execute the following in a separate thread:

```
socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
socket.close()
```

Calling [`socket.shutdown()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.socket.shutdown) will make `rfile.readline()` return an empty `str` or `bytes`, depending on the version of Python (2.x or 3.x respectively).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you just go ahead and close it, from another thread, then the thread that was trying to read from it will return with an error.  If you don't have multiple threads, then you will have to refactor to use non-blocking mode (option `os.O_NONBLOCK` when you open the socket).

Comment: `EBADF` is what you'll get, at least on my system.  But this is dangerous unless you are *absolutely sure* that no thread will attempt to start reading from the socket after you close it — you'll have to use a mutex — because otherwise you end up with a race condition against opening new sockets and getting the same fd.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the variety of other somewhat confused, often fragile or dangerous answers, this is a tricky question.  Fortunately, you can side-step all of these issues by using non-blocking sockets instead.  Consider this approach (using Twisted for simplicity):

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineOnlyReceiver
from twisted.protocols.policies import TimeoutMixin
from twisted.internet import reactor

class YourClientProtocol(LineOnlyReceiver, TimeoutMixin):
    def connectionMade(self):
        # Initiate the timeout
        self.setTimeout(30)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        # Reset the countdown
        self.resetTimeout()
        # And process the line somehow
        if line == "great justice":
            print "for the win!"

    def timeoutConnection(self):
        # Report the timeout
        print "Timed out waiting for a line"
        # Drop the connection
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        # Let the program complete
        reactor.stop()

# Set up a connection
clientFactory = ClientFactory()
clientFactory.protocol = YourClientProtocol
reactor.connectTCP(HOST, PORT)

# Start the main loop, which can handle timed and 
# network events simultaneously
reactor.run()
```